# Should I Get My Vision Corrected Prior to 1st Class AME?

Tags: medical

I have 20/30 vision in both eyes. I don’t have glasses or a prescription for corrective lenses. 1st class AME requires correctable to 20/20. I need to obtain a 1st class certificate for an aviation scholarship. Do I need to get corrective lenses (to get to 20/20) before I have my evaluation? My optometrist is booked for the next six months. I’m wondering if I should schedule the AME or not.

Comment: Is this for the U.S. / FAA rules? Or elsewhere?

Answer (score 6):

If you are asking about FAA regulations in the U.S., in my opinion you should clarify the issue with your AME's office.

However, I expect that it would be difficult for the AME to confirm that you would have 20/20 distant visual acuity unless you could demonstrate that during the 1st class exam. Based on the information you've provided in your question it appears that you would need to have corrective lenses to do that.

[14 CFR Part 67.103 EYE](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-67/subpart-B/section-67.103) (a) states the following and may be helpful:

> **Eye standards for a first-class airman medical certificate are:**
>
> > (a) **Distant visual acuity of 20/20 or better in each eye separately, with or without corrective lenses**. If corrective lenses (spectacles or contact lenses) are necessary for 20/20 vision, the person may be eligible only on the condition that corrective lenses are worn while exercising the privileges of an airman certificate.

*(emphasis is mine)*

Answer (score 4):

Almost certainly yes - the eyesight test is part of the assessment, and you'll be expected to demonstrate your corrected and uncorrected vision at the time.

If you fail, then you may not get given your medical. Specifically here in the EU, your medical (if necessary) will be marked that you must wear glasses for it to be valid. Again, your AME can't very well include this if you don't have glasses at the time.